# How fetch a gem, that depends of a git source, in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems

I have two gems (**A** and **B**) that depends of one another gem (gem **X**). The gem **X** is in my git repository.

When i use the gem **A** or **B** in a rails app, the gem **X** is not being fetched.

The Gemfile of **A** and **B** are like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# gem's dependencies in A.gemspec
gemspec

gem 'x', :git => 'https://user:password@bitbucket.org/x/X.git', :branch => 'master'
```

In the Gemfile of my rails app i added the following line:

```
gem 'A', :git => 'https://user:password@bitbucket.org/a/A.git', :branch => 'master'
```

So, my question: how can i use the gem A or B, that depends of X, in my rails app? Is this possible?